# action not found on alternate builds

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I have a form like the following.

```
<form method="post" action="paste">
```

The page rendering the form and the action the form points to are both part of the same controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Paste()
        { // some field operations here.}
}
```

Now, in first build the form submission causes a 404 with a message `The resource cannot be found.` I edit the cshtml file and replace `paste` in the form tag with itself, build again and deploy and the form works fine. Why is it happening so and how can I correct the behaviour ?

Comment: What happens if you decorate the `Paste` action with `[HttpPost]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work by adding the [HttpPost] attribute to your action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Paste()
    { // some field operations here.}
```

Comment: Please explain the behaviour of success on alternate builds.